# Tesseract: in Cocoa Touch Framework cannot open eng.traindata file

Tags: ios, ocr, tesseract

I got following errors when I run iOS application, with embedded binary which is my own cocoa touch framework with following dependencies

`1) TesseractOCR.framework`
`2) CoreImage.framework`
`3) libstdc++.6.0.9.tbd`
`4) libz.tbd`

I got `1) TesseractOCR.framework` by using instructions (Non-Cocoapods Installation) from this link
https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/issues/340#issuecomment-351479701

The reason I do not use TesseractOCR from Cocoapods is that I need to create custom OCR framework which will be used by clients.

I also have `tessdata` folder reference with trained data files inside my own cocoa touch framework.

When I tried to create and debug `single view app` with above listed dependencies and the `tessdata`, which is working fine.

But my iOS application with my framework will get following error message

> Error opening data file file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9669A787-B512-4C02-8DA7-8E77FBEF7B8A/Documents/tessdata/eng.traineddata 
>   Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
>   Failed loading language 'eng'
>   Tesseract couldn't load any languages!

Here is my folder structure of my framework.

[image]

Here is the structure of my work flow. Please help me.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for My-Application (Client App) to work, I have to add `tessdata` as a reference to client app. Currently, there are no other ways without it.

Comment: How did you do this?

Comment: Drag and drop `tessdata` folder under same level as project folder name in xcode and make sure to choose `Copy items if needed` and `Create folder references` accordingly.